# toggleEdit textarea with embeded html style tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have a very simple issue. I am using [toggleEdit](http://alz.so/toggleedit/) to allow the user to edit/preview some html.  For those who are unfamiliar with toggle edit, all it does is when you call `toggleEdit()` on an `<input/>` it creates a `<div/>` with whatever value is in your `<input/>` element.  When you `toggleEdit("preview")` it shows the `<div/>`, and when you `toggleEdit("edit")` it shows your `<input/>` field.

For my case I am using it to show "embedded html." The user basically enters some html, clicks preview and it shows. I am trying to find a way to "rerender" the div so that embedded style elements can be used.

For example.

In the text area the user enters:

```
<style type="text/css">
   ul {  list-style-type: circle;  }
</style>

<ul> <li> This is a test </li>  </ul>
```

In my case, the style is ignored.  But if I were to use inline styles they would work.  I tried replacing the div text, but that did not work.

I'm sure this is a simple rerednering issue.. just can't find an easy way to search for it.

---

**Edit**

As requested here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8f72/14/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help greatly if you were to post a live version of your code for proper examination to take place. In any case, it doesn't seem like style=type declarations through js insertions are supposed to work. Inline however does and that is why you see tools like firebug and so forth relying upon line-styles for on-the-fly css additions to the dom that work on real-time.

Comment: Just posted a link above for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried your JSFiddle example and the embedded css is working for me. What I noticed is that the list-style:circle wasn't very visible cause it needed some left margin or padding, but the circle is there. Here's a screenshot: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/513/jsfiddle.jpg/

Comment: I just tested this as well, which makes me think there must be something else going on... I'll have to go back and create a better test case.

Comment: Did you replicate my result then? Ok, I'll await your next test case.

Answer (score -2):

Try the [important rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) in your style to override other declarations:

```
ul { list-style-type: circle !important; }
```

Comment: Yea I tried that yesterday, and today and still does not work.